# Android Project to Cordova plugin - R.java not found / created

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, r.java-file

This is actually one of my first Cordova plugin using lots of device specificities.

**Context**

My android project is composed of :

- libs (vendors libs such as  libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar or android-support-v4.jar)
- res  (anim / drawable / values / xml ...)
- src (my project Java specific sources)

In android, once the project is compiled, there is a specific file created to handle all my project definition and dependencies : **com.myProject.R.java**
The android project referenced lots of R.drawable (for instance) and needs therefore to import the com.myProject.R.java

I want to use that Android Project into a Cordova plugin.

I have therefore created a fresh new directory for my cordova plugin:
 - created my node interface
 - copied my Android Source
 - updated plugin.xml to reference mt files / intent ...

**What does work**

With that cordova plugin created, I added it to my existing ionic project 
This project was using **ANT** for build is it is 6months old and has not yet been updated to gradle new build system.

> I copied mannually the eclipse generated R.java to ANT-BUILD
>   com/myProject/R.java and my project is working properly.

This one time step allows us to export easily a full android project to a Cordova plugin

**What does not work**

Ionic has updated it's build process and is using now Gradle.
After updating my android platform (with cordova platform rm android / cordova platform add android)

I have the lots of following errors now (others issues are same) :

```
platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\main.xml:30: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/vehicleDetailsDefaultTxt').
```

This issue is linked to the fact that my `com.myProject.R.java` is not founded / generated within the gradle build and the references object can't be found.

I have tried to manually put the R.java file into:

- platforms\android\build\intermediates : (many different dir) - same problem
- platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\debug : This is where the file Shall be IMO but before packaging, gradle clean  the directory

How shall I reference the R.java ? Or how shall I auto-compile that R.java ?
Or even better, how can I make an Android project (with layout / resources ...) an Cordova project so that I prevent any manual steps like I did before?

Feel free to ask me another other information concerning that issue. I'll answer ASAP